# Self-joining table and matching multiple rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access, subquery

Consider the following many-to-many table:

```
FK_Composition | FK_Part | Position | Quantity
---------------+---------+----------+---------
101            | 2001    | -3       | 1
101            | 2002    | -2       | 2
101            | 2003    | -1       | 1
101            | 2011    |  0       | 1
102            | 2001    | -2       | 1
102            | 2002    | -1       | 2
102            | 2003    |  0       | 1
102            | 2012    |  1       | 1
```

The objective is to find compositions that are *pretty much* the same as a certain composition by comparisson. 
"Pretty much" meaning:

1. The compared composition consists of the same parts as the original, apart from the part with the highest position
2. All parts have to be on the same *relative* position (Positions [-3,-2,-1,0] would be allowed when comparing a composition with the positions [-1,0,1,2])
3. Each occurence of a part should have the same quantity
4. The compared composition has no more parts than the original

Going by these rules, composition 102 is *pretty much* the same as 101.

Of course, there's more fun to be had with my question: Our Entity Framework only allows uses of simple SELECT queries **and** we're supposed to support both SQL Server Databases as well as Access "Databases". The query should support both systems and temp tables and loops are a no go.

I've worked with different Databases for a while, but I don't remember I've ever had to match multiple values from multiple rows in a self-join like this before. Yet, I find it reasonable to assume that there *should* be a simple way to achieve this. Is there?

Bonus question: I'm thinking of querying the data I need in seperate parts in our .NET application and let Linq do its magic, but there's concern that certain clients' computers might not very well handle too much in-memory data. We're talking about data with maybe up to a million rows, depending on the clients' databases. Is this a valid concern?

Edit - As requested in the comments, here are some counter-examples with compositions that should not match when compared to composition 101:

```
FK_Composition | FK_Part | Position | Quantity | Reason
---------------+---------+----------+----------+------
151            | 2001    | -3       | 1        | Part 2004 is no match
151            | 2002    | -2       | 2        | 
151            | 2004    | -1       | 1        | 
151            | 2011    |  0       | 1        | 
152            | 2001    | -2       | 1        | Has a different number of parts
152            | 2002    | -1       | 2        | 
152            | 2012    |  0       | 1        | 
153            | 2001    |  1       | 2        | Position 1 has the wrong quantity
153            | 2002    |  2       | 2        | 
153            | 2004    |  3       | 1        | 
153            | 2011    |  4       | 1        |
```

Comment: You should probably add a lot more test cases to explain a few other nuances.  Such as Do they have to have the same number of parts too?  E.g. what if 103 has 6 parts and the first 3 match the first 3 of 101 would that be a close match?

Comment: I think 1) is saying they have to have the same parts (except the highest position). But I agree more examples would be very helpful - at the very least a counterexample of something which should fail to match. Also will you ever get a set of positions that aren't sequential e.g. (1,2,2,3) or (1,3,6578)? And does the quantity of the highest part need to match?

Comment: @Matt Yes, they do have the same number of parts. Both the number of positions as well as the quantity of each position has to match.

Comment: @JamesCasey Their should not be a set of positions that aren't sequential, as far as I'm aware of. At least their can't be something like (1,2,2,3) because the position is part of the primary key. The quantity of the highest part needs to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sql-server version.  This would NOT work in ms-access and honestly all of the sub queries and derived tables and things that would be necessary to do this in msa-access don't interest me in writing sorry.  But it should give you an idea of some logic etc.

http://rextester.com/FSJG1811 example showing it working

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (FKComposition INT, FKPart INT, Position INT, Quantity INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (101,2001,-3,1),(101,2002,-2,2),(101,2003,-1,1),(101,2011, 0,1)
,(102,2001,-2,1),(102,2002,-1,2),(102,2003, 0,1),(102,2012, 1,1) -- 3 of 4 match but not the highest position
,(103,2002,-2,1),(103,2003,-1,2),(103,2004, 0,1),(103,2012, 1,1) -- 3 of 4 match but not 1 of the middle positions
,(104,2001,-2,1) --match but last and highes position
,(105,2001,-3,1),(105,2002,-2,2),(105,2003,-1,1),(105,2011, 0,1) --exact match
,(106,2001,-5,1),(106,2002,-2,2),(106,2003,-1,1),(106,2011, 0,1) --exact match except PositionDifference

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKComposition ORDER BY Position) as PosRowNum
       ,Position - COALESCE(LAG(Position) OVER (PARTITION BY FKComposition ORDER BY Position),Position) as PosDif
       ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FKcomposition) as PartsCount
       ,MAX(Position) OVER (PARTITION BY FKComposition) as HighestPosition
    FROM
       @Table
)

    SELECT
       CASE WHEN c1.FKComposition < c2.FKComposition THEN c1.FKComposition ELSE c2.FKComposition END as FKComposition
       ,CASE WHEN c1.FKComposition < c2.FKComposition THEN c2.FKComposition ELSE c1.FKComposition END as FKCompositionOfMatch
       ,c1.PartsCount
       ,COUNT(c2.FKComposition) / 2 as MatchedPartsCount
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN c2.HighestPosition = c2.Position THEN c2.HighestPosition END) as MatchIncludesHighest
    FROM       
       cte c1
       INNER JOIN cte c2
       ON c1.FKComposition <> c2.FKComposition
       AND c1.FKPart = c2.FKPart
       AND c1.Quantity = c2.Quantity
       AND c1.PosRowNum = c2.PosRowNum
       AND c1.PosDif = c2.PosDif
    GROUP BY
       CASE WHEN c1.FKComposition < c2.FKComposition THEN c1.FKComposition ELSE c2.FKComposition END
       ,CASE WHEN c1.FKComposition < c2.FKComposition THEN c2.FKComposition ELSE c1.FKComposition END
       ,c1.PartsCount
       ,c2.PartsCount
    HAVING
       c1.PartsCount = c2.PartsCount
       AND (
          COUNT(c2.FKComposition) = (c1.PartsCount * 2) --there are 2 combinations 101 to 105 and 105 to 101 so must double the count
          OR (COUNT(c2.FKComposition) >= (c1.PartsCount * 2) - 2)
             AND COUNT(CASE WHEN c2.HighestPosition = c2.Position THEN c2.HighestPosition END) = 0
          )
```

You will notice there are a couple of more test cases.  In the end 101 should match 102 & 105 and 102 will match 105 (and 101 by proxy)  I simplified to 1 combination instead of duplicate such as 101 matches 102 and 102 matches 101 you will only get 101 matches 102.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below that will find the relative positions of the parks for a Composition... you can use in in there where clause. Sorry I can't spend any more time to help with the rest.

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ISNULL(main.Position - sub.Position,0) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS ReletivePositions FROM
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY FK_Part DESC)  as RowNumber
FROM @PARTS P1
WHERE FK_Composition = 101 /* << CHANGE THIS TO FK_Composition IN QUERY */ ) main
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER (ORDER BY FK_Part DESC)  as RowNumber
FROM @PARTS WHERE FK_Composition =  101  /* << CHANGE THIS TO FK_Composition IN QUERY */ ) sub ON main.RowNumber + 1 = sub.RowNumber
ORDER BY main.FK_Part DESC
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS ReletivePositions
```